# Mouse Wheel sometimes fails in XPRA

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, xpra

I have an XPRA client running on Windows 10 and the server is running on Ubuntu 16.04.  Usually everything connects and XWindows applications opened in Ubuntu show up on the Win10 desktop without any issues.  From time to time, the mouse wheel stops responding on the XPRA applications.  Rebooting both machines and reconnecting from scratch doesn't always help.  There's nothing obvious in the ~/.xpra logs.  What could be the cause?  How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that upgrading to the most recent Beta has fixed my problem.  The beta actually seemed more stable for me than the released version of the software.

You can get it here:

http://xpra.org/beta/windows/